# selenium cgi script python

Tags: python, firefox, selenium, cgi

I wrote a CGI script for getting some data from a form and then used selenium (python ) to log in using that data, but I am always getting ": Message: Can't load the profile. Profile Dir: %s If you specified a log_file in the FirefoxBinary constructor, check it for details. "

This file is saved as website.py

This is my code...

```
#!/usr/bin/python
print "Content-type: text/html"
from urllib2 import urlopen
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import sys
import MySQLdb
from BeautifulSoup import *
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
import cgi
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()


print """<html>
    <head>

    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="left-column">


        </div>
        <div class="right-column">
            <h1 class="main-heading">Post your Comments on sample.com: Step 1</h1>
                """
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
if form.getvalue("fullname"):
    name=form.getvalue("fullname")
    email = form.getvalue("email")
    display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
    display.start()

    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get("https://sample.com")


    # phone = form.getvalue("phone")
print """           <form action="website.py" method="post">
                <i>Your Name:</i><br/><input type="text" name="fullname" class="textbox"><br/>
                <i>Your Email:</i><br/><input type="text" name="email" class="textbox"><br/>
                <i>Your Phone Number: (optional)</i><br/><input type="text" name="phone" class="textbox"><br/><br/>
                <input class="btn" type="submit" value="Next" style="width: 150px; height: 40px; font-size: 14px;">
            </form>

        </div>
    </body>
</html> """
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is that your python CGI script is running as the server, not as you, and what you're seeing is a permissions problem of some kind. . .